# jade web services integration gateway

Tags: rest, soap, pug

I have gone through the following url for building webservices in jade http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/WSIG_Guide.pdf

Last page gives you instructions to run sample examples given by wsig....

When i tried running runMathAgent.bat ...I am getting the following output

```
Jul 15, 2016 12:57:55 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.management.AgentManagement initialized
Jul 15, 2016 12:57:55 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.messaging.Messaging initialized
Jul 15, 2016 12:57:55 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.resource.ResourceManagement initialized
Jul 15, 2016 12:57:55 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.mobility.AgentMobility initialized
Jul 15, 2016 12:57:55 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFO: Service jade.core.event.Notification initialized
Jul 15, 2016 12:57:55 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl startBootstrapAgents

> SEVERE: Cannot create agent MathAgent1: Class
> com.tilab.wsig.examples.MathAgent for agent ( agent-identifier :name
> MathAgent1@WSIGTestPlatform ) not found - Caused by: 
> com.tilab.wsig.examples.MathAgent

Jul 15, 2016 12:57:55 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
INFO: --------------------------------------
Agent container Container-2@192.168.1.3 is ready.
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured solution for my problem. To run jade web services examples u need to deploy using ant (ant deploy-examples) and configuration includes juddi version of apache. This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run jade web services examples by deploying the exemples: using ant deploy-examples command.